# Laptop keyboard problem

Tags: windows-7, laptop, keyboard, mouse

I have bought a new HP Compaq Presario CQ62 and I installed Windows7 ultimate but I can't use the function key and caps lock and my mouse cannot use the scroll-wheel.

What could be the problem?!

Comment: *Please* try to give your question a descriptive title, proper grammar and a detailed description of your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure all the drivers that came with your HP Compaq Presario CQ62 are installed.